# How to install Sopcast Player in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, 14.04, software-installation, sopcast

I have tried to find some PPA's for Ubuntu 14.04 but didn't find any. So I tried to install the package for previous releases, with no luck and a lot of dependencies issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Credit to : Maurizio Siagri**

There isn't sopcast for 14.04 at any PPA's at this moment but I found a working and easy to understand advice at http://mauriziosiagri.wordpress.com/tag/sopcast/ .

Although it's written for 13.10, it works for 14.04 too.

From my experience, you should first install pythong-glade2, otherwise there will be an minor error which won't effect running the program -- but annoying .

```
sudo apt-get install python-glade2
```

It's a good idea to note down step by step what you do incase you should have problem installing it ( I hope you won't).

Comment: thank you. this guide solved my problem. i'v been able to install it finally, and it was pretty easy. but i'm still having problems as it crashes often, and vlc crashes whenever i put it as the default player. thanks again you rock m8

Comment: My Nvidia GT240 - legacy one with latest opensource driver form xorg-edgers ppa, gets along very well with sopcast. You should probably try to update all concerned X11 libraries and display drivers form there.

Comment: It's `python-glade2`, not `pythong-glade2`.

Comment: wrong spelling correted. Thanks user1880405.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in the following link, works great. I was looking for this for the last month or so!

http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/06/install-sopcast-player-0-8-5-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.